# Difference between flux.parallel.runOn().flatMap( blockingcall //Mono.fromCallable) vs flux.flatMap(blockingcall.subscribeOn() //Mono.fromCallable)

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

What is the difference between below implementation of spawning parallel computation of elements emitted by flux.

```java
Flux.fromIterable(list)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flatMap(items -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> blocking database call).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))
                .map(dbResponse -> dbResponse.stream().map(singleObj-> createAdifferentObject(dbResponse)).collect(Collectors.toList())
                .block()
```

And

```java
Flux.fromIterable(list)
                .flatMap(items -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> blocking database call).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))
                .map(dbResponse -> dbResponse.stream().map(singleObj-> createAdifferentObject(dbResponse)).collect(Collectors.toList())
                .block()
```

For the first piece of code i referred this block

```
  return Flux.fromIterable(urls)
    .flatMap(url -> 
             //wrap the blocking call in a Mono
             Mono.fromCallable(() -> blockingWebClient.get(url))
             //ensure that Mono is subscribed in an boundedElastic Worker
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    ); //each individual URL fetch runs in its own thread!
}
```

from this blog https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers

For the second piece of code, in general in our team or org, everyone uses it. This documentation says, Schedulers.(without new word) creates a shared instance from this link https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html, but in terms of flow, shouldn't that be outside the flatMap? If not how does it work?

Comment: Top one will will create a parallel flux which in turn will set up eecution on multiple cores (which has a setup time) and then try to execute the sequence on multiple cores.

Comment: All this is documented in the official reactor documentation. You should read there before asking, downvoted.

Comment: Parallel Flux is to parallelize CPU intensive operations. For concurrent blocking IO calls the bottom one is the recommended approach.

Comment: Please provide documentation that states differently, subscribe on picks a thread during subscription and stays with it. Dont claim that things are untrue unless you provide documentation that states otherwise. The downvote is for poor research by the person asking the question. So downvote will not get retracted.

Comment: @Toerktumlare the documentation about the schedulers could be a useful read. If you look at the code in the question, there is a subscribeOn inside the flatMap which will ultimately let go of the subscribing thread and continue the work with a new one from the specified Scheduler. Since it's inside the flatMap, each inner Publisher will subscribe on a different thread.

Comment: @Toerktumlare i asked this question because i am confused between the official documentation and the blog post.

Comment: I think i had not asked the question clearly, i have edited now to make it clear. I just wanted the clarity on the semantics of providing the Scheduler. i understand that Scheduler provided in the second block and first block are shared instances and they are not newly created everytime, but in the second block why is the scheduler provided inside the flatMap and not outside like the first one.

Comment: When scheduler is outside of the flatMap, then blocking calls are executed sequentially on a single thread from the selected Scheduler. If it's inside the flatMap, then each blocking call can get its own thread and they can be called concurrently. Level of concurrency depends on the size of the thread pool which backs the scheduler and the concurrency parameter of flatMap (by default 256).

Comment: @MartinTarjányi makes sense, thanks. Looks like Reactive paradigm is going to be fun.